# How to remove a search bar's past searches from local storage?

Tags: javascript, api, local-storage

I created and appended local storage to a search bar and I am trying to get it to remove searches after it hits a certain number, but I cannot seem to get it to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```js
// save the searches to storage
var saveBook = (newBook) => {
    let bookExists = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage["books" + i] === newBook) {
            bookExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bookExists === false) {
        localStorage.setItem('books' + localStorage.length, newBook);
    }
    renderBook();
}

// render the books to the dropdown menu
var renderBook = () => {
    $('#menu-title').empty();
    let lastBookKey = "books" + (localStorage.length - 1);
    lastBook = localStorage.getItem(lastBookKey);
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        let book = localStorage.getItem("books" + i);
        let bookEl = `<li id="recall-book"><a id="searchedBook">${book}</a></li>`;
        $('#menu-title').prepend(bookEl);
    }
        let newBooks = $("<menu-title>")
            .addClass("button")
            .text(bookEl)
            .click(() => {
                runApp(event.target.innerHTML);
                event.target.remove();
            });
        if (lastBook < 8) {
            newBooks.prependTo($("#menu-title"));
        } else {
            $("#menu-title")
                .children()
                .last()
                .remove()
                .prepend(lastBook);
        }
}
```

Comment: giving some more details about what you want, and what is not working, where the think the problem is, would help people to give you better and quick answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Your issue lies in `saveBook`

In this `for...loop`

```js
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage["books" + i] === newBook) {
            bookExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

`i` will only ever reach `localStorage.length-1` because `i` needs to be smaller than `localStorage.length`. Then when you don't find the book, you set the `localStorage` key to the following:

```js
localStorage.setItem('books' + localStorage.length, newBook);
```

This, `localStorage.length`, is obviously greater than `localStorage.length-1`. So what will happen, is that your `for...loop` will never check the last book of `localStorage`.

#### I Would suggest deciding on a naming scheme and then moving forward.

At the moment, you're checking for 0 index based naming i.e. `book0`, `book1`. However your books are 1 index based naming i.e. `book1`, `book2`.